# What could cause a socket to close quickly after every HTTP transaction?

Tags: delphi, http, sockets, keep-alive

I have a Delphi 6 application that talks to an external device that acts as an HTTP server.  I am using the ICS TWSocket components for this application.  I open up a socket to talk to the device and handle the necessary header and body crafting to talk to the server.  In other words, I am not using the ICS HTTP client component but using the lower level TWSocket component and handling the necessary HTTP "handshaking" myself.

The headers I craft and send to the external device have the keep-alive flag set to TRUE.  On my system, after I send anything to the external device, the connection will stay open continuously and will not close until approximately 30 seconds of inactivity occurs (30 seconds where I don't make any requests of the external device as an HTTP server).  I don't know if the external device closes it or if Microsoft Windows does it.  But the important point is that normally I can do multiple sends and the connection will stay open until I send nothing for about 30 seconds.  This works fine and is what my code expects.

However, on some of my users systems the socket is closing after every send.  I do have code that checks for a closed socket and attempts a reconnect to the external device if necessary, but does not expect to have to do a reconnect with each transaction.

My questions are:

- Is there a system setting for sockets that might be causing this anomalous behavior on some users systems?
- If so, are there Windows API function calls I can use to query the offending parameter and then set it to the expected close on 30 seconds of inactivity instead of with each transaction?
- If so, can I, or how do I do it in a manner that will not adversely affect any other programs running on the users system?

Comment: the external device is allways the same version, using the same configuration, and not connected over some kind of proxy? Because it seems like differences are caused by either different servers or something in the middle.

Comment: That might be just HTTP/1.0 running on that particular device. Version 1.0 did not have persistent connections. In any case, wireshark is your friend.

Comment: First, please use Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark to see how the connection is closed (which side sends the TCP RESET), and then you can start analysis further.

Answer (score 7):

The server is closing the socket. There are three possible reasons for this:

- The client made a HTTP/1.0 request
- The client set a `Connection: close` header in the request
- The server does not support persistent connections

HTTP/1.0 did not support persistent connections, and the server would be correct in closing the socket after a HTTP/1.0 request.

HTTP/1.1 specifies that a connection is implicitly persistent, unless the client specifies a `Connection: close` header. The server would be correct in closing the connection if it receives this header. If the server does not support persistent connections, it would also be correct in closing the connection.

If you are using HTTP/1.1, you can force the connection to be persistent (as long as the server supports it) by sending a `Connection: keep-alive` header. You should then also send a `Keep-Alive: timeout=<secs>, max=<max-requests>` header, where `<secs>` and `<max-requests>` are integers representing the desired behaviour.

Comment: For HTTP 1.0, a client can send a `Connection: keep-alive` request header to ask for a persistent connection.  Most HTTP 1.0 servers support that as an unofficial extension, as `keep-alive` is not enabled by default in HTTP 1.0.  The server's `Connection` response header will indicate whether the keep-alive was honored or not.

Comment: @DaveRandom - please see my comment below and to Remy thank you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau (and Dave) - The server appears to be HTTP 1.0 according to the response header: "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" + "Server: WYM/1.0".  I always had the "Connection: keep-alive" line but just added a "Keep-Alive timeout=30 max=3" line to my request.  The server returns the following lines in the response header with a 200 OK status: "Connection: Keep-Alive" + "Keep-Alive: timeout=3600, max=108000".  Does that (necessarily) indicate success despite the HTTP 1.0 support?  However, I checked the debug logs from the user and those two keep-alive lines are indeed coming back from the server already.

Comment: @RobertOschler: the version of the response cannot be newer then the version of the request.  If the request is HTTP 1.0, the response will be HTTP 1.0, even if the server supports newer HTTP versions. If the response returns a `Connection: keep-alive` header then the connection is persistent on the server side, so the client can reuse the connection to send the next request.  If the client waits too long and the keep-alive timeout elapses before the next request is sent, the server will have closed the connection and the send will fail, in which case the client can simply reconnect and send.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - re: request version.  I pointed that out because after I tried changing my request to HTTP 1.1 I still got back HTTP 1.0 from the server.  So I still don't know why the socket is closing since it looks like that despite the server support HTTP 1.0 and returning the proper Keep-Alive lines to indicate it, the socket closes after every transaction.  I'll try to get the user to run WireShark or similar to see who is closing the connection.